# I have a galaxy image and I only want to plot the 500th row

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The file is 1000 by 1000 and I want to plot all the x values but only the 500th row of my data. My code so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import scipy.ndimage
from scipy import *

data = fromfile("m33.dat",dtype=int16)
data_fortran=data.reshape((1000,1000),order="FORTRAN")
data2 = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(data_fortran,5,mode="nearest")

#plot m33.dat into a contour plot
plt.imshow(data2,interpolation="none",cmap="binary")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plt.imshow(data2[499].reshape(1,-1),interpolation="none",cmap="binary")
```

Since Python uses 0-based indexing, the 500th row would be found at index value 499.

Comment: I tried using data2[499] and it gave me the TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data

Comment: My mistake. To make the row 2-dimensional, you could use `reshape(1, -1)`. The `-1` gets replaced by whatever positive integer makes sense.